# Gunicorn-Django: django project not found

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I've been trying to set up my production server (Linode 512) by Django, Gunicorn, nginx, I'm getting errors in nginx and gunicorn. As the nginx part purely relates with the server issues, I gotta post that in serverfault. But for Gunicorn error, it is something related with my project structure

```
Django Project/
  apps/
  confs/
    development/
    production/gunicorn.conf
  settings/
    custom.py
    database.py
    development.py
    production.py
    default.py
  static/
    js/
    css/
    admin/
  templates/
  manage.py
  urls.py
```

This structure is working fine in Django development server but when I try with Gunicorn, it shows `RuntimeError("django project not found")` The full error details is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5235542)

Gunicorn setup:

```
import os

def numCPUs():
    if not hasattr(os, "sysconf"):
        raise RuntimeError("No sysconf detected.")
    return os.sysconf("SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN")

bind = "unix:/opt/Project1432/shared/gunicorn.sock"
workers = numCPUs() * 2 + 1
pidfile = "/opt/Project1432/shared/Project1432.pid"
logfile = "/opt/Project1432/shared/Project1432.log"
daemon = True
```

Project path:

```
/opt/Project1432/releases/current/Project1432/...
```

Could anyone guide me to solve this?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Gunicorn run command:
I run this command inside project path which given above.

```
gunicorn_django --config /opt/Project1432/releases/current/Project1432/confs/production/gunicorn.conf
```

Comment: are you using virtualenv ? can you post the command line who start this gunicorn deamon ?

Comment: yes. I'm using virtualenv. I updated my question for the command

Comment: Can you post any solution you find mk..thx

Answer (score 2):

it look to me that the project is not in the path of gunicorn.

personally, I use `manage.py run_gunicorn` and i pass all the config args by command line
and For the Path, I use virtualenv and I source the bin/activate in my shell scrpt

this is my bash script :

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             myProject.exemple.com
# Required-Start:       $syslog $nginx
# Required-Stop:        $syslog $nginx
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description:    the django fast_cgi portal for myProject.exemple.com
### END INIT INFO

# with this config :
#  the project is in /home/web/prod/myProject.exemple.com/src/myProject/
#  the socket is in /var/run/django/myProject.sock   
#  the log files is /val/log/nginx/myProject.exemple.com/gunicorn.log
#  the pid file is /var/run/django/myProject.pid      

# note, for debuging purpose, you can set a DEBUG env variable to prevent gunicorn to fork and to see all the output.
# ie :  sudo DEBUG=True /etc/init.d/django_myProject start                                                                                                                                                                                              

if [ -f  "/lib/lsb/init-functions-color"] ;
then
  .  /lib/lsb/init-functions-color
else
  . /lib/lsb/init-functions
fi

# not exactly used by workon, but used to source the activate
WORKON_HOME=/home/web/prod/Envs                                                                                                                                                                                                              

# change on eveny new project                                                                                                                                                                                                                
PROJECT_NAME=myProject                                                                                                                                                                            
DOMAINE=$PROJECT_NAME.exemple.com                                                                                                                                                                                                         

# fixed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
PIDFILE=/var/run/django/$PROJECT_NAME.pid                                                                                                                                                                                                    
LOGFILE=/var/log/nginx/$DOMAINE/gunicorn.log                                                                                                                                                                                                 
SOCKFILE=/var/run/django/$PROJECT_NAME.sock                                                                                                                                                                                                  
SOCKET=unix:$SOCKFILE                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#SOCKET=192.9.201.3:8050                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#This is the command to be run, give the full pathname                                                                                                                                                                                       
PROJECT_DIR=/home/web/prod/$DOMAINE/src/$PROJECT_NAME/                                                                                                                                                                                       
DAEMON="$PROJECT_DIR/manage.py run_gunicorn"                                                                                                                                                                                                 
USER=www-data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
GROUP=www-data                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
WORKERS=2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

# could be changed                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

#DAEMON_OPTS="run_gunicorn --workers 1 \
#                          --worker-connections 5 \
#                          --daemon\
#                          --user www-data\
#                          --group www-data\
#                          -t 30\
#                          --bind unix:$SOCKET \
#                          --pid $PIDFILE \
#                          --error-logfile /var/log/nginx/$DOMAINE/gunicorn.log"
#                    --daemon \


DEBUG_ARGS="        --user=$USER \
                    --group=$GROUP \
                    --workers=$WORKERS \
                    --bind $SOCKET \
                    -t 90 \
                    --settings=$PROJECT_NAME.settings.prod \
                    --name=$DOMAINE"

DAEMON_OPTS="       $DEBUG_ARGS \
                    --pid=$PIDFILE \
                    --daemon \
                    --log-file=$LOGFILE \
                    --log-level=info"


start()
{

  cd "$PROJECT_DIR"
  log_begin_msg "starting django website" "$PROJECT_NAME"
  mkdir -p `dirname $SOCKFILE`
  chown www-data:www-data  `dirname $SOCKFILE`
#  echo "$SOCKET" |  grep '^unix:' > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
#  if [ ! -e "$SOCKFILE" -a "$?" -eq "0" ] 
#  then
#    log_warning_msg "creation du socket $SOCKFILE"
#    
#    mkfifo $SOCKFILE
#    
#  fi
  if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ]
  then
    ps faux | grep -v grep | grep "$DAEMON" | grep `cat $PIDFILE` > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      log_failure_msg "fichier pid deja present avec un pid existant"
      log_end_msg 1
      return 1
    fi
    rm "$PIDFILE"
    log_warning_msg "pid file deja existant"
  fi
  if [ -f "$WORKON_HOME/$PROJECT_NAME/bin/activate" ];
  then
    . $WORKON_HOME/$PROJECT_NAME/bin/activate 
  else
    echo "impossible d'activer l'environement $WORKON_HOME/$PROJECT_NAME/bin/activate"
    exit 1
  fi
  if [ ! -z  "$DEBUG" ] ;
  then
    echo "sourcing $WORKON_HOME/$PROJECT_NAME/bin/activate"
    echo $DAEMON $DEBUG_ARGS
    $DAEMON $DEBUG_ARGS
  else
    $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
  fi
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    log_end_msg 0
  else
    log_end_msg 1
  fi


}

stop()
{
  log_begin_msg "stoping django website" "$PROJECT_NAME"
  if [ -f  "$PIDFILE" ]
  then
    start-stop-daemon --oknodo --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE 2> /dev/null
    rm "$PIDFILE"
    log_end_msg 0
  else
    log_failure_msg "pid file absent for $PROJECT_NAME django website"
    #log_end_msg 1
  fi

}

status()
{
  if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ]
  then
    # fichier pid existant
    ps faux | grep -v grep | grep $DAEMON | grep `cat $PIDFILE` > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo "$PROJECT_NAME django website running"
    else
      echo "WARN !! pid file present but $PROJECT_NAME django website stopped"
    fi
  else
    ps faux | grep -v grep | grep $DAEMON > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo "WARN !! $PROJECT_NAME django website apear to be running but don't have a PID FILE"
    else
      echo "$PROJECT_NAME django website stopped"
    fi
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
  ;;
  stop)
    stop
  ;;
  restart)
    stop
    sleep 2
    start
  ;;
  status)
    status
  ;;

  *)
  echo "Usage: "$1" {start|stop|restart|status}"
  exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way that I could make this setup to work? Also could you share your setup?